# Old group still visible in terminal after changing group name

Tags: gnome-terminal

I have renamed user group name using

```
groupmod -n [newname] [oldname]
```

and group name was changed successfully. The old group name is not even existing in the system.

However, when starting new terminal I still see

```
username@oldgroupname:~$
```

Is there any way to change it?

Comment: The prompt string is usually `username@hostname` rather than `username@groupname`

Comment: That makes sense ... Thanks